# Check if XML-node has attribute with Linq C#?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

How can I check and see if a node actually has a certain attribute? I have an XML-file containing several nodes looking like this:

```
<Field From="OldString" To="NewString" />
```

So far so good. The problem is that this structure is about to be changed to that some nodes will look like this:

```
<Field From="OldString" To="NewString" PrefixValue="OptionalAttribute" />
```

Now, when the PrefixValue is present I am supposed to prepend the value in that attribute to a string, and that is not very difficult, but I have run into some problems when I try to see if the PrefixValue attribute is present at all for a node. In the instances where no PrefixValue is present, the attribute PrefixValue will not exist in the node at all. How would I go about checking to see if the attribute exists with a Linq-expression?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Well, it depends what you want to do. If you want to use it in a projection, you can use:

```
(string) element.Attribute("PrefixValue")
```

That will return null if the attribute is missing, which is useful.

If you want it in a where clause, use something like:

```
where element.Attribute("PrefixValue") != null
```

Comment: Essentially, I just want a null value to be returned if the attribute is missing altogether as a first step. Thanks!

Comment: @Ziggler: That suggests you're using an `XNode` rather than an `XElement`. We can't see any of your code, but basically you want to use `XElement`...

Comment: If it is XmlDocument, I am getting error XNode doesnot have Attribute property or method...and if it is XDocument, I have Attribute method for XElement but not string input..

Comment: @Ziggler: I have no idea what you mean I'm afraid, but it sounds like you should ask a new question showing us your code.

Comment: My question is if we take element as XElement in above answer... element.Attribute("PrefixValue") is showing me error since Attribute method is asking for XName not string.

Comment: @Ziggler: But there's an implicit conversion from `string` to `XName`, so it will be fine. That code *does* work when the compile-time type of `element` is `XElement`.

Answer (score 5):

```
if ((string)level1.Attribute("customer_code") != null)
{
   newBox.customer_code = (string)level1.Attribute("customer_code").Value;
}
```

The code above should take care of checking if the attribute exists.

Without the if statement you will get an object not set to an instance error.