# Check if any XML nodes exists with Specific Attribute using LINQ C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xelement

This is my XML:

```
<configuration>
    <Script name="Test Script">
        <arguments>
            <argument key="CheckStats" value="True" />
            <argument key="ReferenceTimepoint" value="SCREENING" />
            <argument key="outputResultSetName" value="ResultSet" />
        </arguments>
    </Script>
</configuration>
```

I am trying to use this linq statement to grab an `argument` element's `value` attrbiute if a specific `key` attribute exists.

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(configFileName);
var AttrVal = from el in root.Elements("Script").Elements("arguments").Elements("argument")
            where el.Attribute("key").Value == "CheckStats"
            select el.Attribute("value").Value;
```

Then I want to try and parse the attribute `value` into a boolean:

```
bool checkVal;
if (AttrVal != null)
{
    if (!bool.TryParse(AttrVal.First().ToString(), out checkVal))
    {
        throw new Exception(string.Format("Invalid value"));
    }
}
```

This code works if there is an element with that attribute, but if there isn't one, I get a `System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements`.

How can I get around that?
I thought by checking `if (AttrVal != null)` it would work.
Should I replace that with `if (AttrVal.FirstOrDefault() != null)` or something similar?
Thanks

Comment: have u tried if (AttrVal.FirstOrDefault() != null)  by yourself before asking this question

Comment: @K.B - Yes I did, and I still got the same error.

Comment: in which line you are getting this error

Comment: @K.B - The `if(!bool.TryParse ...)` line.

Comment: You need to check that the attribute exists in your `where` before attempting to read its value - see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2506840/61470

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In if statement, you can write

```
if (AttrVal != null && AttrVal.Any())
```

**EDIT**: I'm wrong. The exception should come from First(), not any of Elements(). Old answer:

```
from el in root.Descendants("argument")
```

Or

```
from el in root.XPathSelectElements("./Script/arguments/argument")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: I implemented the `AttrVal.Any()` check in the `if` statement and it looks like that was the part I was missing.

Comment: sorry. I updated my answer a few minutes before your comment.

Answer (score 1):

you have to check  if there is already your attribute in the element    `where el.Attributes("key")!=null&&`

```
XElement root = XElement.Load("config.xml");
            var AttrVal = from el in root.Elements("Script").Elements("arguments").Elements("argument")
                          where el.Attributes("key")!=null&&  el.Attribute("key").Value == "CheckStats"
                          select el.Attribute("value").Value;

            bool checkVal;
            if (AttrVal != null)
            {
                if (!bool.TryParse(AttrVal.First().ToString(), out checkVal))
                {
                    throw new Exception(string.Format("Invalid value"));
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to eliminate those pesky null checks - seek ahead with `XPath` to determine whether a node with both the necessary attributes (viz `key="CheckStats"` AND a `value`) exists, then parse it.

```
     bool checkVal;

     // using System.Xml.XPath;!
     var el = root.XPathSelectElement(
                    "/Script/arguments/argument[@key='CheckStats' and @value]");
     if (el != null && !bool.TryParse(el.Attribute("value").Value, 
         out checkVal))
     {
        throw new Exception(string.Format("Invalid value"));
     }
```